# S3 logs do not appear in targeted bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets, one named `A` and another named `logs`. I went to the permissions page for `A` and enabled service logging, and set the target to `logs` bucket. According to the AWS documentation, this should enable logging.

> Amazon S3 uses a special log delivery account, called the Log Delivery
>   group, to write access logs. These writes are subject to the usual
>   access control restrictions. You must grant the Log Delivery group
>   write permission on the target bucket by adding a grant entry in the
>   bucket's access control list (ACL). If you use the Amazon S3 console
>   to enable logging on a bucket, the console both enables logging on the
>   source bucket and updates the ACL on the target bucket to grant write
>   permission to the Log Delivery group.

I let the buckets sit for hours before uploading a file to `A`, but I see no logs anywhere. Did I understand the above paragraph wrong and have to generate a bucket policy for `logs`? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: It *should* enable logging, but check the permissions on the target bucket.  It shouldn't require a bucket policy (and if you have a bucket policy, it must not inadvertently block logging), but you should see an entry in the permissions for the bucket.  Check that?  Also ensure that the two buckets are in the same region.  The console should force that, but this could be the issue, if not.

Comment: >but you should see an entry in the permissions for the bucket
Not sure what this means. Do you have an example of what it would look like? Nothing seems different than before except in LogDelivery I see `Read bucket permissions` and `Write permissions` checked.

The buckets are in the same region.

Comment: Well, i deleted all the buckets and tried again and it's working. Not sure why it wasnt working for the other bucket but this makes my question obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of reference is wrong.

"If you use the Amazon S3 console to enable logging on a bucket, the console both enables logging on the source bucket and updates the ACL on the target bucket to grant write permission to the Log Delivery group."

It can't guaranty that it always updates the ACL on the target bucket successfully. If you logging target is in "Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)", update will fail. So your logging bucket won't work as expected.

You should check logging bucket. Go to Permissions, check if "S3 log delivery group" is enabled in Public Access.