# Server access logging on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Delving into the AWS world, I have created two buckets in my AWS. The first one called `BucketA` (holding the files) and the second one called `BucketB` (holding the log files). `BucketA` will be hosting images which will be accessible from the outside world as these are not sensitive. Let's assume the images are called `image1.png`, `image2.png`, `image3.png` and the pattern continues.

Both my buckets are in the same region.

The web addresses for each file is as follows: (these are sample links and are not real and at the moment apparently someone owns them and they are in an access denied mode)

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/logging-bucket-444324324/image1.png
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/logging-bucket-444324324/image1.png
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/logging-bucket-444324324/image1.png

My goal is to accomplish the following: **To know which IP address, at what time opened and viewed a certain image.**

I have set the `Log Delivery` for `S3 log delivery group` in `BucketB` to read and write, and for `BucketA` I have enabled the `Server access logging` and set the `Target Bucket` to be `BucketB`.

Now, for testing purposes, I am trying to enter the links above, but I am not getting any logs written in the `BucketB`.

1. Can I accomplish what I am trying to accomplish by this method? (I Know I might use AWS CloudTrail with Data Events but I want to use good-old Server Logging)
2. Does this type of loggin work on basic link visit? Or it has to be done programmatically with a specific HTTP GET request so that a log appears?
3. Do I need to add any type of Bucket Policy or ACL than the ones automatically generated by allowing log access using the normal web console?
4. Does a request gets logged even if the access is denied to that object ?

There is a similar question here: [S3 logs do not appear in targeted bucket](https://serverfault.com/questions/914384/s3-logs-do-not-appear-in-targeted-bucket) which was solved by deleting all the buckets and creating new ones, which isn't really providing a solution to the problem and is the aws version of an IT saying `Please restart the computer and it should work.`

Comment: *"which isn't really providing a solution to the problem"* agree 100%.  What you describe should be working, and should capture *all* the bucket activity logs, including simple "click the link" -- but logging does take a little while to get started and are not written instantaneously.  I has been a few hours, since you posted, so... do you see any log entries, yet?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Indeed, you were right, the logs did appear on my second bucket after couple of hours.